# Log4Net Viewing using a Circular Buffer

Tags: c#, wpf, buffer, log4net

I am using Log4Net in a WPF app. I have it working where I am using the NotifyAppender to update a `TextBox` on my form. This comes in with the oldest on the top, newest on the bottom.

I need to reverse that and have the newest on top. I would also like to be able to "freeze" the updating of the view so that a user can scroll through the messages, and then be able to "unfreeze" it. Any messages that where "buffered" can now be displayed. I'm assuming I need to capture the messages and place them in a collection, sort it, and then display them in the view but I'm not sure how to capture the messages.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [MemoryAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.html) and access this somehow from your WPF application. I think however that you would be better of to write your own appender (Hint: Check out the source code of the MemoryAppender) and allow this appender to communicate more directly with your application (i.e. you could use a service locator in order to connect to a service that receives your log messages. This service in turn is used by your ViewModel (assuming you use MVVM) for populating your `TextBox`. This probably works best if you use some IoC container, but this is not strictly necessary.)